Getting GPSD to automatically determine which USB port the device is on
I have a Rock Pi S that's got a USB hub on it with 5 devices connected.  When the whole system powers up they get assigned /dev/ttyUSBX ports in an arbitrary order, depending on how fast the individual devices connect.   One of the five devices is a GPS receiver.
GPSD is configured to look for one of these.  How can I get it to pick the correct one?  In /etc/default/gpsd i have this:
START_DAEMON="true"
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
GPSD_OPTIONS="/dev/ttyUSB0"
GPSD_SOCKET=”/var/run/gpsd.sock”

which is fine as long as the GPS receiver boots up first.
I've seen reference to USBAUTO=true online, but I've not been able to get that to do anything.
All five devices use a CH340 interface chip, so to the OS they appear as five identical devices.  I can manually work out which one is which by monitoring the data streams coming from them.  Can GPSD do the same?

Might be the quotes USBAUTO="true", not sure though.
